# Mi aplicacion en android no funciona bien en android 9

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en android studio, la cual descarga vídeos de un servidor y los reproduce todo funcionaba bien hasta la versión 7.1, pero estaba probando la misma aplicación en un dispositivo android 9.0 y solo funciona si el dispositivo esta conectado a wifi y cuando conecto por LAN no me reproduce los vídeos.¿Alguien sabe si en android 9 necesito algún permiso nuevo para poder descargar o reproducir a través de LAN?

Comment: Hola Alexander, podrías poner el error que te aparece y el código de tu aplicación

Comment: Aquí tienes la información de los permisos en Android 9 [Cambios en el comportamiento: Todas las apps](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all)

Comment: En si no es un error, solo que trata de descargar los vídeos cuando lo conecto por cable de red pero no los descarga , pero por wifi funciona correctamente

Comment: Que se muestra en el LogCat? es importante saber.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.app.DownloadManager.query(android.app.DownloadManager$Query)' on a null object reference esa es la excepción que se lanza